# React-router v4. How to navigate between routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, browser-history, react-router-v4

Routing doesnt work.

It renders only first component Cloud on /, but when I add other routes in doesn`t work

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

// import components
import Cloud from './components/Cloud';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';
import Contacts from './components/Contacts';
import Account from './components/Account';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

const App = (props) => {
return (
    <Router history={history}>
        <section>
            <Sidebar/>
            <div className="main-content">
                <Header/>
                <div id="page-wrapper">
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Cloud}/>
                    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
                    <Route path="/contacts" component={Contacts}/>
                    <Route path="/account" component={Account}/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Footer/>
        </section>
    </Router>
    );
};

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

What am I doing wrong ?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EngK.png) and  [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2KVG.png)

And how to jump between /home and /login routes if user cookies expired ?

Answer (score 0):

Just put a `/` in front of your paths, i.e,

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Cloud}/>
<Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
<Route path="/contacts" component={Contacts}/>
<Route path="/account" component={Account}/>
```

Comment: It won`t help. I just forgot to write this / here